# HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation happens in asynch mode and not in synch mode

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, servlets, nio

I have 2 webservlet one is being run in Asynch mode:

```
@WebServlet(name="myServlet", urlPatterns={"/asyncprocess"}, asyncSupported=true)
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="app.processasynch", havingValue="true")
public class AsyncServletGW extends HttpServlet {

    @Autowired
    private Stage1WorkersPool wp;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProcessBusinessLogicStage1Impl.class);

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{

        AsyncContext aCtx = request.startAsync(request, response);

        int paymentId = (new Random()).nextInt(100000);
        WorkerThread workerThread = wp.getPool().get(paymentId % wp.getNumWorkingThreads());
        ThreadUnitWorkImpl py = new ThreadUnitWorkImpl();
        String msgBody;

        if ("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())){
            msgBody = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
            py.setXmlRequest(msgBody);
            py.setACtx(aCtx);
            aCtx.getResponse().setContentType("text/plain");
            py.setResponse(aCtx.getResponse());
        }else{
            LOGGER.error("Not a POST request");
        }


        LOGGER.debug("Servlet Processing : " + py.toString());
        workerThread.addUnitOfWork(py);
    }
}
```

And the other in Synch mode

```
@WebServlet(name="myServlet", urlPatterns={"/syncprocess"})
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="app.processasynch", havingValue="false")
public class SyncServletGW extends HttpServlet {

    @Autowired
    private ProcessInSynchStages synchP;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProcessBusinessLogicStage1Impl.class);

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{

        ThreadUnitWorkImpl py = new ThreadUnitWorkImpl();

        String msgBody;

        if ("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())){
            msgBody = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            py.setXmlRequest(msgBody);
            py.setResponse(response);
        }else{
            LOGGER.error("Not a POST request");
        }

        ArrayList<ThreadUnitWorkImpl> tuwList = new ArrayList<>();
        tuwList.add(py);
        synchP.runInSynch(tuwList);
    }
}
```

When calling the asynch I get the notorious exception : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]

While debugging I have noticed that after the first time calling the asynch servlet the second, third etc. are always delayed. After 1-2 seconds the above exception is thrown and the servlet is being processed.
In synch mode however everything runs smoothly... any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake from my end... I forgot to close the AsyncContext by running the complete() methoid....